# How to set pulseaudio to send proper S/PDIF (or IEC958) signal via HDMI?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, spdif

In some former release of Ubuntu I could make audio work, if I forced pulseaudio to convert to 44100 Hz, but it does not seem to work in 20.04 (at least most of the times). https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1829364

I wonder which settings I should use in daemon.conf or elsewhere to make audio work via HDMI cable using my hardware?